# Securing access to Java-Script files

Tags: javascript, php, download, lamp, authorize

I have a site that grants access to content in various forms (PDF, MP3, MP4 etc) to authenticated users. The site has been developed for me by a 3rd party developer on LAMP. Users authenticate with the application using a username/password stored in a MySQL DB. They do not authenticate with Apache, MySQL or any other mechanism.

Recently, a penetration test of the site identified a few apparent vulnerabilities. The one that has me scratching my head is the requirement for authentication to download javascript files. Obviously the browser needs access to this JS content to make the application run and this means exposing at least some files publicly.

My questions is this: Is there a way to prevent users who have not logged in to the application from accessing certain files?

I have seen solutions like a `.htaccess` version suggested for content files. 
e.g.

```
      Options +FollowSymLinks  
      RewriteEngine on  
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../authorize.php?file=$1 [NC]
```

If I split up the JS code into public/private folders is there a way to serve up java-script i this manner rather than just including it wholesale? Will this work for javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you require a separate path for authentication only ... a login path. This path will allow only public assets to be downloaded. Successful authentication redirects the user to your secure path. Logout action redirects user to the login path.

Answer (score 0):

> If I split up the JS code into public/private folders is there a way to serve up java-script i this manner rather than just including it wholesale? Will this work for javascript?

In `authorize.php`, psuedocode, check logged in status and existence of files, returning private over public for logged in users

```
if $_SESSION['logged in'] && exists '/private/' . $_GET['file']
    print '/private/' . $_GET['file']
else if exists '/public/' . $_GET['file']
    print '/private/' . $_GET['file']
else
    die
```

You then combine this with your example `.htaccess` and include the files exactly as if they were normal `.js` files, letting Apache convert those links into the correct php line for your php script to do the logic for you.

Comment: Thanks. I took that and modded it a little and it worked a charm. I didn't use a .htaccess file but included the redirect in the apache site.conf/ Check user is logged in. If they aren't, stop right there.  
`code` if(!(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id']!='' ))  
die("You are not authorized to access this resource.");  
#strip leading '/' from path and then check if it exists  
$relative_path = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1);  
if (file_exists ($relative_path))  
readfile( './private' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);  
else  
die("File not found." . $relative_path);